# Adding a div element's width

Tags: javascript, dom

I have an div element and two buttons one increase the other decrease, so I what I want is that once I click one of the buttons I want it to increase or decrease.

```
<button class = "increase">increase</button>
<button class = "decrease">decrease</button>
<div class = "expand"></div>
<script>
let increase = document.querySelector(".increase");


let div = document.querySelector(".expand")

let decrease = document.querySelector(".decrease");


increase.addEventListener("click",function(e){
let add = 10;
let getWidth = window.getComputedStyle(div).width;

if(window.getComputedStyle(div).width === "1px"){
div.style.width+=parseInt(getWidth)+add+"px"
}


})

</script>
```

```js
let increase = document.querySelector(".increase");


let div = document.querySelector(".expand")

let decrease = document.querySelector(".decrease");


increase.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let add = 10;
  let getWidth = window.getComputedStyle(div).width;

  if (window.getComputedStyle(div).width === "1px") {
    div.style.width += parseInt(getWidth) + add + "px"
  }


})
```

```html
<button class="increase">increase</button>
<button class="decrease">decrease</button>
<div class="expand"></div>
```

Comment: I skip that because is abvious that I have it in my IDE.

Comment: Ok I did it check it out.

Comment: `console.log(getWidth)` after you set its value and see what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseInt(getWidth) + add + "px"` won't do any math. It will just concatenate all the individual values. You must group the numbers together to have the math happen first and then concatenate after you get that result.

You also have to either have some content in the `div` for it to have an initial `height` that's not zero or give it a `height` via CSS.

This is much simpler than you think. See the inline comments:

```js
let increase = document.querySelector(".increase");
let decrease = document.querySelector(".decrease");
let div = document.querySelector(".expand")
let amt = 10;

increase.addEventListener("click", changeWidth);
decrease.addEventListener("click", changeWidth);

function changeWidth(e){
  // Determine + or - based on the data-operation HTML attribute
  // If it's + we'll add the amt, but if not, amt becomes -amt
  changeAmt = this.dataset.operation === "+" ? amt : -amt;
  
  // Strip off the "px" with parseInt first
  let currentWidth = parseInt(getComputedStyle(div).width);
  
  // Do math first and concatenation second
  div.style.width = (currentWidth + changeAmt) + "px"
}
```

```css
.expand { border: 1px solid black; height:1em; }
```

```html
<button class = "increase" data-operation="+">increase</button>
<button class = "decrease" data-operation="-">decrease</button>
<div class = "expand"></div>
```

Comment: @JuniorDevSchl48 You're welcome. Don't forget to up vote the answer as well as mark it as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top-left of the answer.